# One way secure DES key transfer to defend against attacker

Tags: cryptanalysis, des

I have a question about cryptanalysis.

A transmit message to B with radio waves, A use modulator to transmit bytes with radio, B obviously use demodulator. A encrypts and B decrypts the messages received from A, a certain point an attacker is able to always get the key used by the two even though they always change it, B has only DES as an algorithm to decrypt and only that can use, how can A do it to take out the attacker?

- B transmits the key openly in modulation.
- Key changes every 20 seconds.
- Transmission is one-way from B to A, there is no interaction.

Comment: Welcome to CSE. Sorry, but I fail to understand _"a certain point an attacker is able to always get the key used by the two even though they always change it"_ for several reasons: A) syntax: is a leading _"at"_ missing?. B) is _"a certain point"_ fixed in space or/and time? C) What does _"always"_ imply in term of information assumed available to the attacker? Also, _"A transmit message to B"_ and _"Transmission is one-way from B to A"_ are incompatible. Hence I deem the question unclear. Also, there seems to be no on-topic solution.

Answer (score 1):

**update:** The key is transmitted openly via some modulation.

Modulation is security by obscurity. In the real world, we assume that the attacker knows everything but the key, i.e. words we live under [Kerckhoffs principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).

Since you have one-way transmission, you can use RSA-KEM to transmit the message with the key.

Better use [crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/authenticated_encryption) which is faster and better. And, It can encrypt and authenticate messages with secret-key cryptography.

**Note:** Don't use DES. DES insecure in today's standard and you cannot defend yourself against a dedicated DES attacker.

1. [Hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/); running with two [p3.16xlarge][5] instances on AWS, one probably will find the key on average in about 0.9 days. Because that's 46G tries/second per GPU and 16 GPUs.
2. [crack.sh](https://crack.sh/) can search the key in ~26 hours with a single machine.
3. [crack.sh](https://crack.sh/) also produce a chosen-plaintext attack utilizing a rainbow table to recover DES key in 25 seconds in 2017.

Comment: I forgot, the key change every 20 seconds, but attacker know always the key..
I m thinking how A could made to take out attacker, but I ven t idea

Comment: Then, the attacker knows your weak keygen method or A or B sells it.

Comment: No attacker, can get key, because channel in B when pass key to DES insecure, so attacker sniff every time from this channel new key..

Comment: Ah, Then you need Diffie-Hellman key exchange. Who told you that keys can be transmitted openly.

Comment: Diffie-Hellman I don t think, because A can only transmit (send message) and B can only recive message, they cannot exchange messages..

Comment: Then RSA-KEM is a choice. It is one way.

Comment: So B must have RSA implemented, so the only way is that?
Anyway the only way is try to obscure the key?I thought something about change in modulation, but I ven t knowledge and idea about it

Comment: Modulation is obscurity. In the real world, we assume that the attacker knows everything but the key. Also, you can use crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305 faster than RSA.

Comment: do you have to use DES?

Comment: yes DES or anyway symmetric algorithm..

Comment: If satisfied, could you accept and close this question? And, next time, please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: I m not satisfied, anyway I close the question